# Browser_cookies3 chrome not pulling all cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm running the following code:

```
import requests
import browser_cookie3
cj = browser_cookie3.chrome()
url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox'
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
my_cookies = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(r.cookies)
print(my_cookies)
```

my_cookies only ever has 3 or 4 cookies. Whereas if I hit F12 and look through the console there are always at least a dozen cookies for the given url. I've tried different urls (not just gmail).

Is this a case of me not using browser_cookies3 correctly or some kind of limitation I can't get around? Thanks.